# c# keep adding random numbers everytime the button is clicked

Tags: c#, for-loop

I want to create a program where every click generates a random number and on top of that every time it is clicked the new random number generated is added to the previous number. 
Sorry I am very new to C# so. So far I have, but I want to add the numbers, so how would I do it thank you.

```
 private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            Random r = new Random();
            int a = r.Next(0, 100);
            label.Text = a.ToString();




    }
```

Comment: What UI framework are you using?

Comment: Question shows a serious lack of basic understanding of very simple programming concepts like addition and saving results in a variable.  Go back one step and figure out how to create a variable. Figure out how to add something to that variable.  Then you will have the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just declare a variable to store `sum`:

```
Random r = new Random();
int sum = 0;
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     sum += r.Next(0, 100);
     label.Text = sum.ToString();
}
```

Comment: This will work so long as the OP is not using Asp.Net.

Answer (score 1):

Just concatenate the string

```
    Random r = new Random();
    int a = r.Next(0, 100);
    label3.Text += a.ToString();
```

Answer (score 0):

its a bit Easyer.

```
private void btn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

        Random r = new Random();
        int a = r.Next(0, 100);
        label.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(label.Text) + a);
}
```